# SSRS print as pdf causing extra space

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have built an SSRS report which has a field pulling data from a database.  the field supports HTML, and I've set the property in SSRS to render it as HTML.  The field is within a tablix.

When I run the report in SSRS (not render as PDF) it comes up fine, the tablix ends where the field's date ends.  However, if i run it and render it as PDF there seems to always be some extra space at the end of the field, pushing the tablix further down.  I tried removing all html tags from the data, still leaving the field to render as HTML, same results.  Even without any html tags in the data there appears to be space at the end of field, pushing the tablix end border down.

Can this extra space be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Hvae you tried by removing marging/padding of report from top and bottom section. You can do it by right click on report by selecting "Report Properties" option. that will open dialog and from that you can change top and bottom margin.

please check below image.
[image]

Try this.